# getimagesize() returns no data?

Tags: php, image-processing

I get the following error when trying to upload a .JPG file.

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in H:\Programs\webserver\root\media\images\upload.php on line 43
```

The following is part of the upload.php file:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $album = $_POST['album'];

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {

        // get dimensions of uploaded images
        echo $temp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; //location of file
        echo $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key]; //image type
        echo $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]; // image size
        >> line 43 >>**echo $size2 = getimagesize($temp); //function to get info of file and put into array**
        echo $width = $size2[0]; // first part of the array is the image width
        echo $height = $size2[1]; // second part fo the array is the image width

        if($type == 'image/jpeg')
        {
        $filetype = '.jpeg';
        }else{
        $filetype = str_replace('image/','',$type);
        }
        $random_name = rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
        $path = 'img/'.$random_name . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $thumb_path = 'img/thumb_/'.$random_name .$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
```

I have another .jpg image file that I have been uploading to test which uploads fine, also .png and .gif files also upload fine.

Just to add that I tried a couple more image files of a similar size and received the same error. 
The first Image file was 4.2MB the second was 5MB. Why would the file size stop it uploading?

Also when using $_FILES['files']['error'][$key]; - it returns 1.

This is what i get when using print_r:

```
Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => DSCN0354.JPG ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: How big is the image you are uploading, that fails?

Comment: Have you considered using `print_r($_FILES)` to see what's actually in the array? If not, do it and add the output to your question.

Comment: I guess you didn't paste your full code here.

Comment: `Why would the file size stop it uploading?` because php settings limit it. Look for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. And 4.2 MB is not similar to 5 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at the knowns:

- You can upload .jpg, .gif, .png no problem
- You are having problem uploading a specific .jpg image

These knowns lead me to believe that the problem image is too big for the current allowed `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini settings:

```
$ -> php -i | fgrep -i size

upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
```

Try increasing the size to 6M or 8M and your bigger image should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you add some error handling, you can easily see what the problem is using the [error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
  if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
  {
     // good
  }
  else
  {
     // not good, see messages on http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `===` in your comparison. If for some reason the value wasn't set at all, you would think that everything was ok. (`UPLOAD_ERR_OK = 0 == NULL`)

Comment: @Michael Mior You're right, I just copied this blindly from the php manual but I'd probably use a `===` myself. I wonder why they didn't in the php manual though, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php ...

Comment: Hmm, odd. I thought I've seen `===` elsewhere in the manual before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for [$_FILES['error'][$key]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) before accessing tmp_name - the file was not uploaded, either because it is too big or some other reason (you will find out by the value of 'error' field)

Answer (score 1):

`Also when using $_FILES['files']['error'][$key]; - it returns 1.`

Error 1: The uploaded file **exceeds** the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

(see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the filename supplied is empty.

You are using:

```
$size2 = getimagesize($temp);
```

Where do you get $temp from? Is it the foreach() and if it is, you should use $tmp_name instead.

Comment: It's there: `$temp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; //location of file`. Also, the code works but for that particular image